# Getting Specific List From A DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

From the table below, I have a list `x =[2,2,4]` (`x` contains some of the value from the ID column). My task is to use the list `x` and make a new list , `y`, that contains some values from `df["group"]`. So in this case the answer would be `y=[1,9,8]`

```
df=(tabulate({'ID': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'Age': [4, 15, 18, 6], 'Group': [3, 1, 9, 8], 'Color':['R', 'BL', 'G', 'G'] }, headers="keys", tablefmt='fancy_grid', missingval='N/A'))
```

| ID | Age | Group | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | R |
| 2 | 50 | 1 | BL |
| 2 | 18 | 9 | G |
| 4 | 6 | 8 | G |

My approach: I know `.loc`is used for things like this. So I tried doing:

```
y=[]
mask= x == df["ID"] 
y= (df.loc[mask, "group"])
print(y)
```

This unfortunately didn't work. I am quite stuck and don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems like pandas question and  dataframe from pypi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `isin()`+`loc` accessor+`tolist()`:

```
out=df.loc[df['ID'].isin(x),'Group'].tolist()
```

output of `out`:

```
[1, 9, 8]
```